# E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached

Tags: android

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь наполнить созданный RecyclerView элементами, а при открытии активити, в котором он находится, получаю ошибку. Из-за чего это может быть?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chats);

    RecyclerView recList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.cardList);
    recList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recList.setLayoutManager(llm);


    ContactAdapter ca = new ContactAdapter(createList(30));
    recList.setAdapter(ca);

}

private List<ContactInfo> createList(int size) {

    List<ContactInfo> result = new ArrayList<ContactInfo>();
    for (int i=1; i <= size; i++) {
        ContactInfo ci = new ContactInfo();
        ci.username = "@Moon";
        ci.msg = "Hi Luna";
        ci.time = "сегодня, 14:21";

        result.add(ci);

    }

    return result;
}
```

public class ContactAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private List<ContactInfo> contactList;

public ContactAdapter(List<ContactInfo> contactList) {
    this.contactList = contactList;
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return contactList.size();
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ContactViewHolder contactViewHolder, int i) {
    ContactInfo ci = contactList.get(i);
    contactViewHolder.vUsername.setText(ci.username);
    contactViewHolder.vMsg.setText(ci.msg);
    contactViewHolder.vTime.setText(ci.time);
}

@Override
public ContactViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.
            from(viewGroup.getContext()).
            inflate(R.layout.chats_card_layout, viewGroup, false);

    return new ContactViewHolder(itemView);
}

public static class ContactViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    protected TextView vUsername;
    protected TextView vMsg;
    protected TextView vTime;

    public ContactViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        vUsername =  (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.chat_username);
        vMsg = (TextView)  v.findViewById(R.id.chat_msg_content);
        vTime = (TextView)  v.findViewById(R.id.chat_time);
    }
}
```

}

> W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int
>   android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int,
>   boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method
>   in android.widget.ListView

Comment: Добавьте код адаптера.

Answer (score 1):

Видимо баг в Dalvik интерпретаторе, который позволяет переопределять package-private методы. Google признали эту проблему как раз в версии Android Jelly Bean. Вот они собственно пишут:

> If you intend to override a class's method in a different package, declare the method as public or protected.

Во [ссылка](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/verifying-apps-art.html#Object_Model_Changes) на источник.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=1; i <= size; i++) {
```

первый элемент массива с индексом 0

```
for (int i=0; i < size; i++) {
```

Comment: при чем здесь это?

Comment: Переменная i в цикле всё равно не используется